# ¿ Como puedo posicionar un contenedor en medio de dos contenedores que tienen position fixed?

Tags: html, css, position, contenedor

Tengo un contenedor superior (NAVBAR) que tiene la clase position fixed de bootstrap, y un footer que tiene fixed-bottom, quiero tener contenedor en medio de estos 2 pero todo lo que he intentado ha fallado. Se que el nabvar y el footer al tener position fixed se salen del flujo normal y por eso el contenedor que quiero en el medio no respeta la posición de estos, pero como podría ubicarlo en el medio de estos? este tercer contenedor también tiene position fixed ya que quiero scroll en mi página.

¿ Que he intentado ?

se que el tercer contenedor al tener position fixed obedece a las propiedades top, bottom. Inspeccioné la altura que tiene tanto el navbar como el footer y es de 56px, así que intenté aplicar `top: 56px; bottom: 56px;` al contenedor del medio y no se porque solo obedece al top, el bottom no funciona, ademas intente agregar un contenedor padre (img-cont) al contenedor del medio (main) , y jugar con el paddin-top y pagging-bottom del padre pero pasa lo mismo, no me toma el padding-bottom. que podría hacer para resolver este problema?

Estoy trabajando con Angular y Bootstrap 4, pero para compartir el código acá decidí hacerlo en stackblitz y junte todo el html en un archivo y lo mismo con el css, tengo horas en esto y no he podido solucionar, acá está el link de stackblitz:

[código](https://stackblitz.com/edit/html-fvhbvc?file=styles.css)

Acá explico de manera visual lo que quiero lograr:

actualmente está así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ven, el contenedor main (que es el contenedor que quiero en el medio del navbar y el footer) cuándo lo inspecciono me abarca todo el espacio. lo que quiero es que dicho contenedor comience debajo del navbar y termine donde comienza el footer, es decir, que su tamaño solo abarque el cuadro blanco que muestro a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como podría hacer eso?

Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Bueno, si solo te obedece a un lado en dirección vertical, es porque el elemento tiene un alto definido, de lo contrario, se estiraría en ambas direcciones hasta satisfacer las dos restricciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si los 3 contenedores están fixed, dale el tamaño de la pantalla a tu contenedor menos el espacio en pixeles que ocupan tu footer y header, asi:

```
main {
   height: calc(100vh - 112px);
   top: 56px;
}
```

De esta forma el contenedor toma el `height del viewport` menos el alto de tu header y footer juntos, y se coloca a `56px` del top, que es el alto de tu header.

Comment: Esto me funcionó, muchas gracias!

Comment: Disculpa, tendrás tiempo para una consulta en el chat? es sobre el mismo tema, estaré atento a tu respuesta.

Comment: Disculpa amigo, no me había conectado, que necesitas?

Comment: Quería hacerte una consultas referentes al mismo tema, si es posible claro.

Comment: Dime, cual es tu consulta

Comment: Así como lo estoy haciendo está mal? Lo resolví como me comentaste, calculando el 100vh - (altura de los de más elementos) ? Tuve que colocar eso también en las media querías para ajustarlo ya que algunos contenedores cambian su tamaño debido a que modificó la fuente de la letra. No se si hay una mejor forma para evitar hacer esos cálculos, o si es incorrecta la forma que estoy usando?

Comment: No hay problema, para eso son los media queries, aunque si no quieres ajustar de esa forma, dales un height fijo a los otros contenedores, y al ajustar el texto, lo centras con el padding correspondiente, aunque yo seguiría usando el media query.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias. lo único es que en el telefono android la barra donde aparece la url de la página al parecer me roba espacio, porque todo se desajusta, si coloco la la resolución del telefono en en el naveagor de la computadora no pasa nada, el problema es con el navegador del telefono por que aparece la barra de la url y ese espacio ocupado por la barra no es tomado en cuenta  cuándo se usa vh, leí que vh toma en cuenta la mayor altura posible (como si la barra de navegación estuviese oculta siempre) pero como en el navegador móvil la barra se muestra se pierde calculo.

Answer (score 0):

No definas un alto en el elemento, si no, solo va a aplicar la propiedad top.

```css
.position-fixed{
  position: fixed;
}

.top-bar{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: brown;
}

.bottom-bar{
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: pink;
  
}

body{
 height: 100vh;
 background: teal;
}

.bottom-bar,.top-bar{
  height: 57px;
  width: 100%;
}

.content{
  top:57px;
  bottom: 57px;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="position-fixed top-bar">
   Unos links
</div>

<div class="content position-fixed">
   <button>Comenzar</button>
</div>

<div class="position-fixed bottom-bar">
  Texto de footer
</div>
```

> When both top and bottom are specified, position is set to absolute or
> fixed, and height is unspecified (either auto or 100%) both the top
> and bottom distances are respected. In all other situations, if height
> is constrained in any way or position is set to relative, the top
> property takes precedence and the bottom property is ignored.

[Puedes consultar aquí la fuente](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom)

Comment: Ok, eso no lo he leído en ninguna documentación. otra cosa... si tengo un  contenedor padre con altura 100vh y defino un contenedor la altura de un contenedor hijo al 100% el máximo de altura del contenedor hijo sería la altura del contenedor padre?

Comment: ¿De qué manera esto es compatible con las clases CSS implementadas por el OP basadas en Bootstrap?

Comment: Pues en el código fuente de ejemplo que vi, esa parte del problema que quería resolver, no estaba hecha en bootstrap, estaba con CSS puro.

Comment: @JulianProg Si te refieres a tener un hijo dentro del elemento de en medio, que es el que tiene top y bottom, si, si le das 100% va a tener la altura del padre y en cuanto a lo que comentas sobre la documentación, voy a buscar ese fragmento para colocarlo en mi respuesta

Comment: @Unknow Ok, gracias por la ayuda. Una última pregunta... Así como lo estoy haciendo está mal? Lo resolví como me comentaron en la respuesta anterior a la tuya, calculando el 100vh - (altura de los de más elementos) ? Tuve que colocar eso también en las media querías para ajustarlo ya que algunos contenedores cambian su tamaño debido a que modificó la fuente de la letra. No se si hay una mejor forma para evitar hacer esos cálculos, o si es incorrecta la forma que uso?

Comment: No esta mal, ya es opinión de cada quien eso. en mi caso haría lo que ya escribí en mi respuesta. Igual, si el tamaño de tu fuente cambia, también en este escenario en cada media query tendrías que cambiar los valores top y bottom para que el contenedor se estire hasta la nueva distancia que debe tomar en ambos lados.

Comment: La verdad no cambiaría el tamaño de la fuente a menos que fuera muy necesario, el logo también lo dejaría igual en todos los tamaños.

Comment: El problema que tu pregunta expone fundamentalmente es el porque en el elemento se aplica la propiedad top unicamente, cuando al mismo tiempo tienes la propiedad bottom en tu regla de estilo, deberías mejorar el titulo de la pregunta en base a eso. Saludos

Comment: Y como haces? por que por ejemplo el mismo tamaño de letra en una pantalla de escritorio no debería ser el mismo que en una pantalla móvil, no? yo manejo los tamaños de las fuente usando la medida ```rem``` .